# Filling a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I'm new to Python. I'm trying to fill a list with the filenames of a bunch of images in a folder. They all begin with "frameinstance" and are then followed by a number from 0-40, i.e. "frameinstance0.png". I tried the code below, but I'm getting a `MemoryError` error.

```
filenamelist = []
i = 0
for i in range(0,40):
  filenamelist = [str(filenamelist) + "frameinstance" + str(i)]
```

I also tried this. My output was close, but it's not a list.

```
filenamelist = []
i = 0

for i in range(0,40):
  filenamelist = str(filenamelist) + "frameinstance" + str(i)

print(filenamelist)
```

the output is: `[]frameinstance0frameinstance1frameinstance2frameinstance3frameinstance4frameinstance5frameinstance6frameinstance7frameinstance8frameinstance9frameinstance10frameinstance11frameinstance12frameinstance13frameinstance14frameinstance15frameinstance16frameinstance17frameinstance18frameinstance19frameinstance20frameinstance21frameinstance22frameinstance23frameinstance24frameinstance25frameinstance26frameinstance27frameinstance28frameinstance29frameinstance30frameinstance31frameinstance32frameinstance33frameinstance34frameinstance35frameinstance36frameinstance37frameinstance38frameinstance39`

Answer (score 5):

With a basic list comprehension:

```
filenamelist = ["frameinstance{}".format(i) for i in range(41)]
```

---

In the first code, you always change the value of `filenamelist`, by converting it to a string that is longer and longer, which ends up on a `MemoryError`. Check [Ryan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41498006/7051394) for more about this, especially why it does not happen in the second code.

In the second code, you put `[]` in `filenamelist`, and then concatenate it with `"frameinstance" + str(i)`, so at every iteration, you concatenate `"frameinstancei"` at the end of this string.
You end up with a string beginning with `"[]"` and followed by `"frameinstancei"` 40 times.

---

Few things though:

- When you build a list, either use a list comprehension as above for short lists, or use the `append` method. Typically, write `filenamelist.append("frameinstance{}".format(i))` instead of `filenamelist = ...`
- It is considered deprecated to print strings by writing `"blah" + str(x) + "blah"`. Instead, use the `format` method: `"blah{}blah".format(x)`.
- Don't forget that `range(n)` gives you integers from `0` to `n-1`. Therefore, your calls should be `range(0,41)` instead of `range(0,40)`, and could just be `range(41)`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that here:

```
filenamelist = [str(filenamelist) + "frameinstance" + str(i)]
```

`filenamelist` is a list, and `str(filenamelist)` will get you a string representation of that list: brackets `[` and `]`, surrounding a string representation (using [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)) of every item in that list. Let’s look at how that expands:

```
[]
['[]frameinstance0']
["['[]frameinstance0']frameinstance1"]
['["[\'[]frameinstance0\']frameinstance1"]frameinstance2']
['[\'["[\\\'[]frameinstance0\\\']frameinstance1"]frameinstance2\']frameinstance3']
['[\'[\\\'["[\\\\\\\'[]frameinstance0\\\\\\\']frameinstance1"]frameinstance2\\\']frameinstance3\']frameinstance4']
```

Oops. The string representation of a string includes its quotation marks, which have to be backslash-escaped at some point. The backslashes also have to be escaped with another backslash, resulting in exponential backslash growth. Let’s do the math:

- the third string representation has 2 single quotes and 0 backslashes
- every new iteration adds 2 single quotes, 1 backslash for every backslash, and 1 backslash for every single quote

After 40 times around the loop, you end up with a list with one string containing 274 billion backslashes, which is a lot of backslashes to fit in memory.

The issue here was converting the list to a string to concatenate another string to it; you were probably going for concatenating a list to a list instead of a string to a string. That’s doable:

```
filenamelist = filenamelist + ["frameinstance" + str(i)]
```

Typically, though, you would use the list’s `append` method to add one item in place.

```
filenamelist.append("frameinstance" + str(i))
```

Now is a good time to note that Python has some helpful string-formatting tools to format numbers (and more) into strings:

```
"frameinstance%d" % (i,)
"frameinstance{}".format(i)
f"frameinstance{i}"  # Python 3.6+
```

and give a preview of the short way you’ll likely know how to write this in the future!

```
filenamelist = [f"frameinstance{i}" for i in range(0, 40)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the object into the list

```
filenamelist = []
i = 0
for i in range(0,40):
    filenamelist.append("frameinstance" + str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really close with your first pass.  A few things to consider:

1. you don't need to initialize `filenamelist` or `i`.
2. you can use list comprehension to put the for loop inside the list construction `filenamelist = ["frameinstance{}".format(i) for i in range(41)]`

Answer (score 0):

```
['frameinstance{}'.format(i) for i in range(0,41)]
```

1. range(start, end) do not include end `range(0, 40)` will end at 39
2. you need to construct a list not string, use list comprehension is recommend.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
filenamelist = []
for i in range(41):
    filenamelist.append("frameinstance%s.png" % i)
```

Or more pythonic (and faster, for loops are slow in python):

```
filenamelist = ["frameinstance%s.png" % i for i in range(41)]
```

You were getting a MemoryError because you were iteratively adding the list to itself causing you to run out of RAM :P.